# JavaScript - get csv column values

Tags: javascript, csv

How can I get the individual values from the value variable below which gives me a string like this: 1001,10/01/2016,11/01/2016 and assign to each of my variable after the value?

```js
var lines = loadedString.split('\n'); //split on newlines
 for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
 {
  var value = lines[i].split('\t');
  var id;
  var start;
  var end;
 }
```

Comment: Your code is looking reasonable, except that you're not splitting each line on the right character.  Your separator appears to be a comma, not a tab.

Comment: if you're doing `split('\t')` that sounds like a tsv not a csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that:

```
var lines = loadedString.split('\n'); //split on newlines
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        var values = lines[i].split(',');
        var id = values[0];
        var start = values[1];;
        var end = values[2];;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion for thing tomorrow.